# How can I set the JProgressBar to Nimbus Lookandfeel while keeping the rest of UI not to change?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I would like to set ALL of JProgressBar in my Swing application in Nimbus style, while the rest is Windows, Metal, Quauqa, whatever.

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Abandon all hope, ye who mix'n'match PLAFs.

Answer (score 0):

Call `comp.setUI(...)` and `comp.updateUI()` to change the UI of single components.

Comment: @DavidZhang Stack trace please.